# Reseting alarms on reboot using Firebase Realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

My application has some functions, one of them is the alarms, on reboot all alarms are canceled. I am trying to reset them on reboot but I have an issue retrieving the data from the `IntentService` class as follows.

**My Reference and database structure**

```
rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
userRef = rootRef.child(getString(R.string.db_user));
userDataRef = userRef.child(firebaseUser.getUid());
alarmRef = userDataRef.child(getString(R.string.db_alarm));
// ...
reminderRef = userDataRef.child(getString(R.string.db_reminder));
```

**My `IntentService` class**:

```
class BootService extends IntentService {

    public BootService() {
        super("BootService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

        DatabaseReference alarmsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child(getString(R.string.db_user))
            .child()
            // How can I retrieve userId here if user is not logged-in yet?
            // Application may have many accounts in one phone
            // I need to retrieve them all not only one
            .child(getString(R.string.db_alarm));
    }
}
```

The first issue is the *`userId`* mentioned in the comments, the second is will creating the references actually trigger the onChildAdded event?

***Any better approaches to implement this are more than welcome, thanks in advance***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I retrieve userId here if user is not logged-in yet?

You cannot. If the user isn't logged-in yet, it means that you don't know which user will login into your app in order to use that particular id.

> Will creating the references actually trigger the onChildAdded event?

No, only creating a reference, doesn't mean that the `onChildAdded()` method will be triggered. This method will be triggered only when you'll attach a listener on that reference.

Comment: So I need to save the alarms triggered somehow locally and retrieve them from there? There is no other options to retrieve them from database? Even if I save the usersId on that phone and retrieve the reference accordingly? _(For the the `onChildAdded()` I will add the listener, thanks)_

Comment: If you know for sure which user will login and as long as you need that user id to be used in that reference, then you need to save it.

Comment: Only few accounts will be linked to the phone, so I can save their IDs in `SharedReferences` and retrieve it this way, since I don't really care who is going to login again, I just need to reset the alarms for all users. Thanks that helped! I will test it and if it works I will mark the question as answered ;)

Comment: @PeeGee Ok. Keep me poested. Cheers!

Comment: I ended up adding only the alarms needed data to reset them in a local database table using *Room* and accessing it in the service class, thanks :)